# How do I set UTF8 for 404 page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I am using standard method to render a 404 error page:

```
HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
return HttpNotFound($"Запись идентификатором {id} и типом {type} не найдена");
```

But I'd encoded with wrong encoding:
[image]

`HttpNotFound` method does not contain any property related to encoding.
How can I set encoding to `UTF-8` for response?

I also tried to place `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />` in web.config, but it didn't work.

Sniffer's output:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 ?????? ? ?????????????? 'f7c08f77-ffd9-4f85-bca6-6f4d04eba3ff' ? ????? '???????? ?????' ?? ???????         
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcQWxleFxEb2N1bWVudHNcdGVtcGxhdGVzXDFcRjdDMDhGNzctRkZEOS00Rjg1LUJDQTYtNkY0RDA0RUJBM0ZG?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2016 18:48:43 GMT
Content-Length: 6103

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Çàïèñü ñ èäåíòèôèêàòîðîì 'f7c08f77-ffd9-4f85-bca6-6f4d04eba3ff' è òèïîì 'Ïå÷àòíàÿ ôîðìà' íå íàéäåíà</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
...
```

HEX:

```
byte[] arrOutput = { 0x48, 0x54, 0x54, 0x50, 0x2F, 0x31, 0x2E, 0x31, 0x20, 0x34, 0x30, 0x34, 0x20, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0x20, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0x20, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0x20, 0x27, 0x66, 0x37, 0x63, 0x30, 0x38, 0x66, 0x37, 0x37, 0x2D, 0x66, 0x66, 0x64, 0x39, 0x2D, 0x34, 0x66, 0x38, 0x35, 0x2D, 0x62, 0x63, 0x61, 0x36, 0x2D, 0x36, 0x66, 0x34, 0x64, 0x30, 0x34, 0x65, 0x62, 0x61, 0x33, 0x66, 0x66, 0x27, 0x20, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0x20, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0x20, 0x27, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0x20, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0x27, 0x20, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0x20, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x43, 0x61, 0x63, 0x68, 0x65, 0x2D, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x70, 0x72, 0x69, 0x76, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x2D, 0x54, 0x79, 0x70, 0x65, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x2F, 0x68, 0x74, 0x6D, 0x6C, 0x3B, 0x20, 0x63, 0x68, 0x61, 0x72, 0x73, 0x65, 0x74, 0x3D, 0x75, 0x74, 0x66, 0x2D, 0x38, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x53, 0x65, 0x72, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x69, 0x63, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x73, 0x6F, 0x66, 0x74, 0x2D, 0x49, 0x49, 0x53, 0x2F, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x58, 0x2D, 0x41, 0x73, 0x70, 0x4E, 0x65, 0x74, 0x4D, 0x76, 0x63, 0x2D, 0x56, 0x65, 0x72, 0x73, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x35, 0x2E, 0x32, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x58, 0x2D, 0x41, 0x73, 0x70, 0x4E, 0x65, 0x74, 0x2D, 0x56, 0x65, 0x72, 0x73, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x34, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x33, 0x30, 0x33, 0x31, 0x39, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x58, 0x2D, 0x53, 0x6F, 0x75, 0x72, 0x63, 0x65, 0x46, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x73, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x3D, 0x3F, 0x55, 0x54, 0x46, 0x2D, 0x38, 0x3F, 0x42, 0x3F, 0x51, 0x7A, 0x70, 0x63, 0x56, 0x58, 0x4E, 0x6C, 0x63, 0x6E, 0x4E, 0x63, 0x51, 0x57, 0x78, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x46, 0x78, 0x45, 0x62, 0x32, 0x4E, 0x31, 0x62, 0x57, 0x56, 0x75, 0x64, 0x48, 0x4E, 0x63, 0x64, 0x47, 0x5A, 0x7A, 0x58, 0x46, 0x56, 0x44, 0x52, 0x6B, 0x74, 0x63, 0x64, 0x6E, 0x4E, 0x75, 0x58, 0x47, 0x52, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x6C, 0x78, 0x4D, 0x59, 0x57, 0x35, 0x70, 0x64, 0x43, 0x35, 0x56, 0x51, 0x30, 0x5A, 0x4C, 0x4C, 0x6C, 0x42, 0x76, 0x63, 0x6E, 0x52, 0x68, 0x62, 0x46, 0x78, 0x30, 0x5A, 0x57, 0x31, 0x77, 0x62, 0x47, 0x46, 0x30, 0x5A, 0x58, 0x4E, 0x63, 0x4D, 0x56, 0x78, 0x47, 0x4E, 0x30, 0x4D, 0x77, 0x4F, 0x45, 0x59, 0x33, 0x4E, 0x79, 0x31, 0x47, 0x52, 0x6B, 0x51, 0x35, 0x4C, 0x54, 0x52, 0x47, 0x4F, 0x44, 0x55, 0x74, 0x51, 0x6B, 0x4E, 0x42, 0x4E, 0x69, 0x30, 0x32, 0x52, 0x6A, 0x52, 0x45, 0x4D, 0x44, 0x52, 0x46, 0x51, 0x6B, 0x45, 0x7A, 0x52, 0x6B, 0x59, 0x3D, 0x3F, 0x3D, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x58, 0x2D, 0x50, 0x6F, 0x77, 0x65, 0x72, 0x65, 0x64, 0x2D, 0x42, 0x79, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x41, 0x53, 0x50, 0x2E, 0x4E, 0x45, 0x54, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x44, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x57, 0x65, 0x64, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x30, 0x36, 0x20, 0x4A, 0x75, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x36, 0x20, 0x31, 0x38, 0x3A, 0x34, 0x38, 0x3A, 0x34, 0x33, 0x20, 0x47, 0x4D, 0x54, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x2D, 0x4C, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x74, 0x68, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x36, 0x31, 0x30, 0x33, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x3C, 0x21, 0x44, 0x4F, 0x43, 0x54, 0x59, 0x50, 0x45, 0x20, 0x68, 0x74, 0x6D, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x50, 0x55, 0x42, 0x4C, 0x49, 0x43, 0x20, 0x22, 0x2D, 0x2F, 0x2F, 0x57, 0x33, 0x43, 0x2F, 0x2F, 0x44, 0x54, 0x44, 0x20, 0x58, 0x48, 0x54, 0x4D, 0x4C, 0x20, 0x31, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x20, 0x53, 0x74, 0x72, 0x69, 0x63, 0x74, 0x2F, 0x2F, 0x45, 0x4E, 0x22, 0x20, 0x22, 0x68, 0x74, 0x74, 0x70, 0x3A, 0x2F, 0x2F, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x2E, 0x77, 0x33, 0x2E, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x67, 0x2F, 0x54, 0x52, 0x2F, 0x78, 0x68, 0x74, 0x6D, 0x6C, 0x31, 0x2F, 0x44, 0x54, 0x44, 0x2F, 0x78, 0x68, 0x74, 0x6D, 0x6C, 0x31, 0x2D, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x69, 0x63, 0x74, 0x2E, 0x64, 0x74, 0x64, 0x22, 0x3E, 0x20, 0x0A, 0x3C, 0x68, 0x74, 0x6D, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6D, 0x6C, 0x6E, 0x73, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x68, 0x74, 0x74, 0x70, 0x3A, 0x2F, 0x2F, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x2E, 0x77, 0x33, 0x2E, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x67, 0x2F, 0x31, 0x39, 0x39, 0x39, 0x2F, 0x78, 0x68, 0x74, 0x6D, 0x6C, 0x22, 0x3E, 0x20, 0x0A, 0x3C, 0x68, 0x65, 0x61, 0x64, 0x3E, 0x20, 0x0A, 0x3C, 0x74, 0x69, 0x74, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x3E, 0x49, 0x49, 0x53, 0x20, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x20, 0x44, 0x65, 0x74, 0x61, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x64, 0x20, 0x45, 0x72, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x20, 0x2D, 0x20, 0x34, 0x30, 0x34, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x20, 0x2D, 0x20, 0xC3, 0x87, 0xC3, 0xA0, 0xC3, 0xAF, 0xC3, 0xA8, 0xC3, 0xB1, 0xC3, 0xBC, 0x20, 0xC3, 0xB1, 0x20, 0xC3, 0xA8, 0xC3, 0xA4, 0xC3, 0xA5, 0xC3, 0xAD, 0xC3, 0xB2, 0xC3, 0xA8, 0xC3, 0xB4, 0xC3, 0xA8, 0xC3, 0xAA, 0xC3, 0xA0, 0xC3, 0xB2, 0xC3, 0xAE, 0xC3, 0xB0, 0xC3, 0xAE, 0xC3, 0xAC, 0x20, 0x27, 0x66, 0x37, 0x63, 0x30, 0x38, 0x66, 0x37, 0x37, 0x2D, 0x66, 0x66, 0x64, 0x39, 0x2D, 0x34, 0x66, 0x38, 0x35, 0x2D, 0x62, 0x63, 0x61, 0x36, 0x2D, 0x36, 0x66, 0x34, 0x64, 0x30, 0x34, 0x65, 0x62, 0x61, 0x33, 0x66, 0x66, 0x27, 0x20, 0xC3, 0xA8, 0x20, 0xC3, 0xB2, 0xC3, 0xA8, 0xC3, 0xAF, 0xC3, 0xAE, 0xC3, 0xAC, 0x20, 0x27, 0xC3, 0x8F, 0xC3, 0xA5, 0xC3, 0xB7, 0xC3, 0xA0, 0xC3, 0xB2, 0xC3, 0xAD, 0xC3, 0xA0, 0xC3, 0xBF, 0x20, 0xC3, 0xB4, 0xC3, 0xAE, 0xC3, 0xB0, 0xC3, 0xAC, 0xC3, 0xA0, 0x27, 0x20, 0xC3, 0xAD, 0xC3, 0xA5, 0x20, 0xC3, 0xAD, 0xC3, 0xA0, 0xC3, 0xA9, 0xC3, 0xA4, 0xC3, 0xA5, 0xC3, 0xAD, 0xC3, 0xA0, 0x3C, 0x2F, 0x74, 0x69, 0x74, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x3E, 0x20, 0x0A };
```

Answer (score 3):

If you designed your own custom [Custom Error 404 Page](http://media-www-asp.azureedge.net/images-legacy/asp.net/images/hosting/11/aspnet_tutorial11_customerrors_cs_figure05.png), then you could define the encoding to use for the page with `<%@ Page RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>`. As for changing the encoding of the default `HttpNotFound` Error page, I will edit if I can find/come up with something.